# script shell: To tell how many times a user is logged on

Tags: shell, grep, wc

I have got the following:

```
count=$(who | grep $user | wc -l)
echo "$user is logged on $count times."

but it gives me the following output:
 is logged on      0 times.
```

what am I missing here? 
appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `$user`, but need `$USER`. Like,

```
count=$(who | grep $USER | wc -l)
echo "$USER is logged on $count times."
```

I get

```
efrisch is logged on 4 times.
```

Another option is `printf` like

```
printf "%s is logged on %s times.\n" $USER $(who | grep $USER | wc -l)
```

for the same result.